# Should I deal with a private hosted zone myself when deploying a VPC endpoint interface?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-vpc

I'm currently trying to access a VPC endpoint interface for S3 hosted in a VPC from an account, let's say, called Apple from another VPC in another account called Pear. The two VPCs are linked cross-account using a Transit Gateway.

I'm trying to enable the traffic from Pear to leverage an S3 VPC endpoint Interface in Apple. I'd like to keep on using the default service names (`*.s3.amazonaws.com` and co.) instead of using the VPC endpoint custom DNS. To do so, I made sure that:

- the VPC endpoint has private DNS options activated (with true for only the inbound resolver endpoints)
- my transit gateway routes include routes to the subnets where the VPC endpoint is deployed.

Still, I can't resolve properly S3 DNS from the PEar network. A few questions from there:

- Should I manage myself the Private Hosted Zones and other records or is that all managed by the fact of deploying the VPC endpoint interface?
- Should I deploy myself the DNS inbound resolver endpoint and set its IPs in the DHCP options set of the Pear VPC

I followed [this AWS tutorial](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/vpc-interface-configure-dns) but it is pretty elusive on what to set up:

> If you're trying to access an interface endpoint from outside of the VPC (cross-VPC or on-premises), make sure that you have the DNS architecture in place. The DNS architecture should forward the DNS queries for the service domain name to the Amazon-provided DNS server of the VPC where the interface endpoints are created.

What does that mean? Am I on the right track with the inbound resolver endpoint? What should I do "on-top" of just deployed the VPC endpoint interface?

Thanks!!

Comment: Intuition suggests you will need a Route 53 Outbound Resolver and rule on Pear to capture those queries and send them to the remote VPC's resolver, which sounds unnecessarily costly and complicated... but then, accessing an S3 interface endpoint across a transit gateway sounds unnecessarily costly and complicated, too.  What is the motivation for adopting this strategy, if I might ask?

Comment: Pear is on eu-west-1 and Apple on eu-west-3. Our main S3 buckets are eu-west-3 with access policy control on the VPC endpoints ID. Sadly (and afaik), I can't make a eu-west-1 VPCe access a eu-west-3 bucket - Am I wrong?

Comment: No, you're not wrong.